Issues with "Authenticated" Component Not Working in React/TypeScript Project
I'm facing an issue where my Authenticated component in a React/TypeScript project isn't functioning as expected. Specifically, the application isn't routing correctly, and I suspect the problem lies within the Authenticated component.
Here's the relevant code:
<Routes>
  <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
  <Route
    element={
      <Authenticated
        key="authenticated-layout"
        fallback={<CatchAllNavigate to="/login" />}
      >
        <Layout>
          <Outlet />
        </Layout>
      </Authenticated>
    }
  >
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>


The issue seems to be within the Authenticated component. I inspected the Authenticated function, and there are a couple of errors that might be causing the problem:
Error on import React from "react";
Error Message:
Module '"/Users/orlevi/Desktop/OrLevisProjects/Kanban/calm-parts-throw/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flagts(1259)
Errors with JSX Fragments (<>):
This error occurs at several points in the Authenticated function:
// when there is no auth provider
if (!hasAuthProvider) {
  return <>{children ?? null}</>;
}

// when checking authentication status
if (isFetching) {
  return <>{loadingContent ?? null}</>;
}

// when user is authenticated return children
if (isAuthenticated) {
  return <>{children ?? null}</>;
}

// when user is not authenticated redirect or render fallbackContent
if (typeof fallbackContent !== "undefined") {
  return <>{fallbackContent ?? null}</>;
}


Error Message:
Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.ts(17004)
What I've Tried:
I attempted to fix these errors by updating my tsconfig.json file with the following settings:
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,


I also restarted VS Code after making these changes, but the errors persist.
Question:
What could be causing these issues, and how can I resolve them? Is there something wrong with my TypeScript configuration or the way I'm handling the Authenticated component?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I think this error related to TypeScript's strict compiler settings and JSX support. Update your tsconfig.json file with the following settings and see
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

The esModuleInterop and allowSyntheticDefaultImports options were already set correctly in your previous configuration. However, adding the "jsx": "react-jsx" option will enable JSX syntax support for React in TypeScript.
OR
Ensure that you're importing React correctly with an explicit default import:
import React from "react";


hey arun,
i have just exactly those setting in my tsconfig file..
and also the import React is the same as you suggested.
